# Air System Initialization Error - Modelica

Tags: openmodelica

I am trying to model an air system in Twinbuilder using Modelica. But I always get errors:
Error occured when entering initialization mode on air_model1
Error encountered in the Initialize function of user model.
Model:  air_model1.air_model<Modelica_API>
>>
Error encountered while initializing the simulators.
>>  Initialize
Error 10533 - Error encountered during INIT.
>>  Initialize

Help solve this problem. Modelica code below

```
model air_model
    //Interface(s)
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput P1;
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput P2;
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput Vm0;
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput Vm1;
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput Vmb;

    //Declaration(s)
    replaceable constant Real A = 16;
    replaceable constant Real P = 16;
    inner parameter Real dz = 4*A/P;
    replaceable constant Real A9 = 20;
    replaceable constant Real P9 = 18;
    replaceable constant Real A11 = 25;
    replaceable constant Real P11 = 20;
    //Component(s)
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice (
        zeta = 0.02,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        diameter = dz,
        from_dp = false,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice1 (
        zeta = 1.045,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        diameter = dz,
        from_dp = false,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice2 (
        zeta = 1.4,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        diameter = dz,
        from_dp = false);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice4 (
        zeta = 0.02,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        diameter = dz,
        from_dp = false,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice3 (
        zeta = 0.55,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        diameter = dz,
        from_dp = false,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    inner Modelica.Fluid.System system;
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice5 (
        zeta = 1.4,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        diameter = dz,
        from_dp = false,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice6 (
        zeta = 0.55,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        diameter = dz,
        from_dp = false,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice7 (
        zeta = 0.55,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        diameter = dz,
        from_dp = false,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice8 (
        zeta = 0.55,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        diameter = dz,
        from_dp = false,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice9 (
        zeta = 0.55,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        diameter = dz,
        from_dp = false,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice10 (
        zeta = 1.4,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        diameter = dz,
        from_dp = false,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice11 (
        zeta = 0.55,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        diameter = dz,
        from_dp = false);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice12 (
        zeta = 0.55,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        diameter = dz,
        from_dp = false,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice13 (
        zeta = 0.55,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        diameter = dz,
        from_dp = false,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice14 (
        zeta = 0.55,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        diameter = dz,
        from_dp = false,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice15 (
        zeta = 1.02,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        diameter = dz,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice16 (
        zeta = 0.55,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        diameter = dz,
        from_dp = false,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice17 (
        zeta = 0.55,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        diameter = dz,
        from_dp = false,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice18 (
        zeta = 1.2,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        diameter = dz,
        from_dp = false,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice19 (
        zeta = 1.6,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        diameter = dz,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice20 (
        zeta = 1.02,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        diameter = dz,
        from_dp = false,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.Pressure Press1 (redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.Pressure Press2 (redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary boundary3 (nPorts = 1, redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.VolumeFlowRate Volum2 (redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir, allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T boundary (
        nPorts = 1,
        m_flow = 39,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        use_m_flow_in = false,
        m_flow_in = 39,
        T = 293);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.VolumeFlowRate Volum1 (redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir, allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.VolumeFlowRate Volum3 (redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir, allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice21 (
        zeta = 2.2,
        diameter = dz,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        m_flow_nominal = if system.use_eps_Re then system.m_flow_nominal else 100.0 * system.m_flow_small,
        from_dp = false,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice22 (
        zeta = 1.4,
        diameter = dz,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        m_flow_nominal = if system.use_eps_Re then system.m_flow_nominal else 100.0 * system.m_flow_small,
        from_dp = false,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT boundary1 (redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir, nPorts = 1);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe21 (
        length = 400,
        isCircular = false,
        crossArea = A,
        perimeter = P,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe2 (
        length = 400,
        isCircular = false,
        crossArea = A,
        perimeter = P,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe3 (
        length = 200,
        isCircular = false,
        crossArea = A,
        perimeter = P,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe20 (
        length = 100,
        isCircular = false,
        crossArea = A,
        perimeter = P,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        height_ab = 10,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe1 (
        length = 800,
        isCircular = false,
        crossArea = A,
        perimeter = P,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        height_ab = 20,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe18 (
        length = 200,
        isCircular = false,
        crossArea = A,
        perimeter = P,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe22 (
        length = 100,
        isCircular = false,
        crossArea = A,
        perimeter = P,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        height_ab = -10,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe4 (
        length = 790,
        isCircular = false,
        crossArea = A,
        perimeter = P,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        height_ab = -18);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe5 (
        length = 10,
        isCircular = false,
        crossArea = A,
        perimeter = P,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        height_ab = -2,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe6 (
        length = 10,
        isCircular = false,
        crossArea = A,
        perimeter = P,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        height_ab = 0,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe11 (
        length = 200,
        isCircular = false,
        crossArea = A,
        perimeter = P,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe12 (
        length = 200,
        isCircular = false,
        crossArea = A,
        perimeter = P,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe15 (
        length = 800,
        isCircular = false,
        crossArea = A9,
        perimeter = P9,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        height_ab = 20,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe9 (
        length = 200,
        isCircular = false,
        crossArea = A11,
        perimeter = P11,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe10 (
        length = 200,
        isCircular = false,
        crossArea = A11,
        perimeter = P11,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe17 (
        length = 190,
        isCircular = false,
        crossArea = A,
        perimeter = P,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe7 (
        length = 200,
        isCircular = false,
        crossArea = A,
        perimeter = P,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe8 (
        length = 790,
        isCircular = false,
        crossArea = A,
        perimeter = P,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        height_ab = -28,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe19 (
        length = 10,
        isCircular = false,
        crossArea = A,
        perimeter = P,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        height_ab = 0,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe16 (
        length = 100,
        isCircular = false,
        crossArea = A9,
        perimeter = P9,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        height_ab = 20,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe13 (
        length = 100,
        isCircular = false,
        crossArea = A9,
        perimeter = P9,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir,
        height_ab = 20,
        allowFlowReversal = true);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT boundary2 (redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir, nPorts = 1);
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear Valv1 (opening = 0);


equation
    //Connection(s)
    connect(orifice11.port_b, orifice8.port_a);
    connect(Press1.p, P1);
    connect(boundary.ports[1], Volum2.port_a);
    connect(Volum3.V_flow, Vmb);
    connect(Volum2.V_flow, Vm0);
    connect(Press2.p, P2);
    connect(orifice21.port_b, Volum1.port_a);
    connect(Volum1.V_flow, Vm1);
    connect(orifice22.port_b, Volum3.port_a);
    connect(orifice1.port_b, pipe21.port_a);
    connect(pipe21.port_b, orifice3.port_a);
    connect(pipe21.port_b, orifice2.port_a);
    connect(orifice3.port_b, pipe2.port_a);
    connect(Volum1.port_b, pipe3.port_a);
    connect(pipe3.port_b, boundary1.ports[1]);
    connect(pipe3.port_b, Press2.port);
    connect(orifice.port_b, pipe20.port_a);
    connect(pipe20.port_b, orifice1.port_a);
    connect(pipe1.port_b, orifice.port_a);
    connect(orifice16.port_a, pipe1.port_a);
    connect(orifice16.port_a, orifice17.port_a);
    connect(Volum2.port_b, pipe18.port_a);
    connect(pipe18.port_b, orifice21.port_a);
    connect(pipe18.port_b, orifice22.port_a);
    connect(orifice2.port_b, pipe22.port_a);
    connect(pipe22.port_b, orifice4.port_a);
    connect(orifice4.port_b, pipe4.port_a);
    connect(pipe4.port_b, orifice5.port_a);
    connect(pipe4.port_b, orifice6.port_a);
    connect(orifice5.port_b, pipe5.port_a);
    connect(pipe5.port_b, orifice10.port_a);
    connect(pipe5.port_b, orifice9.port_a);
    connect(orifice10.port_b, pipe6.port_a);
    connect(pipe6.port_b, orifice12.port_a);
    connect(pipe11.port_b, orifice12.port_b);
    connect(orifice18.port_b, pipe12.port_a);
    connect(pipe12.port_b, orifice13.port_a);
    connect(pipe12.port_b, orifice14.port_a);
    connect(orifice13.port_b, pipe11.port_a);
    connect(pipe15.port_b, orifice19.port_a);
    connect(orifice15.port_b, pipe15.port_a);
    connect(orifice8.port_a, pipe9.port_a);
    connect(pipe9.port_b, orifice9.port_b);
    connect(orifice17.port_b, pipe10.port_a);
    connect(pipe10.port_b, orifice8.port_b);
    connect(pipe17.port_b, orifice7.port_b);
    connect(boundary3.ports[1], pipe17.port_a);
    connect(orifice6.port_b, pipe7.port_a);
    connect(pipe7.port_b, orifice7.port_a);
    connect(pipe7.port_b, orifice11.port_a);
    connect(Volum3.port_b, pipe8.port_a);
    connect(pipe8.port_b, orifice7.port_a);
    connect(pipe8.port_b, orifice11.port_a);
    connect(orifice16.port_b, pipe19.port_a);
    connect(pipe19.port_b, orifice18.port_a);
    connect(pipe16.port_b, orifice15.port_a);
    connect(orifice14.port_b, pipe16.port_a);
    connect(orifice19.port_b, pipe13.port_a);
    connect(pipe13.port_b, orifice20.port_a);
    connect(Press1.port, pipe18.port_b);
    connect(pipe8.port_a, orifice20.port_b);
    connect(boundary2.ports, boundary.C_in);
    connect(orifice11.port_b, Valv1.port_a);
    connect(Valv1.port_b, orifice13.port_a);
end  air_model;
//---------------------------------------
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpETk.png)

And I have already tried a lot of things to change, which may not be, but there are no more ideas